# "IUserTokenProvider not found" error when calling UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity

Can someone help me with the following code? I'm getting an error on this line and don't understand why:

```
string code = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user.Id);
```

Full code:

```
var user = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);//Find user by email entered
if (user == null)
{
    return View("ForgotPasswordConfirmation");
}
string code = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user.Id);
var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ResetPassword", "Login", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync` method requires a `UserTokenProvider` to be set in your `UserManager`.

You are receiving the error because of a null check in the `GenerateUserTokenAsync` called by your `GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync` method.

Answer (score 0):

A complementary to Scott Brady's answer. You should create the UserTokenProvider manually:

```
// db is of type DbContext or IdentityDbContext
var userManager = new UserManager(new UserStore(db));
var dataProtectionProvider = new DpapiDataProtectionProvider("Test");
userManager.UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<User, Guid>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
var user = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);//Find user by email entered
//rest of the code
```